# Turing machine that computes w#w when the input is w?

Tags: turing-machines

Can someone please describe how such a machine would work?

**My approach**:

Move the head full on the left. Scan the input to verify no # symbol exists. Add # at the end of input. Move the head full on the left. Move one position on the right.

Read character `σ` and replace it with `σ'`. Then go right to the 1st empty char and replace it with `σ`. Then go left till you found the 1st `'` char. Remove the `'` from that char. Move one position the the right and repeat.

When you do that for all characters stop.

Comment: Do you mean a machine that, starting with $w$ on its input tape, ends its computation with exactly $w\#w$ on its tape?

Comment: @Purag Yes, exactly that. I just stared with Turing Machines and have a hard time understanding how this can be done.

Comment: Welcome to Computer Science! What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? We do not want to just do your exercise for you; we want you to gain understanding. However, as it is we do not know what your underlying problem is, so we can not begin to help. See [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/594/the-return-of-the-homework-question) for a relevant discussion. If you are uncertain how to improve your question, why not ask around in [chat]?

Comment: @D.W.♦ updated, can you please verify my approach is correct?

Comment: We discourage "please check whether my answer is correct" questions, as only "yes/no" answers are possible, which won't help you or future visitors. See [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/597/) and [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/519/). It's better to ask about a specific conceptual issue you're uncertain about. As a rule of thumb, a good conceptual question should be useful even to someone who isn't looking at the problem you happen to be working on. If you just need someone to check your work, you might seek out a friend, classmate, or teacher.

Comment: @D.W.♦ I explained the problem and my approach clearly. I am asking for someone who knows the subject better explain if my approach is wrong and why so I can understand it and improve. I am sure other will have the same problem in the future. Unfortunately my teacher doesn't want students in office hours.

Comment: What aspect of your answer are you uncertain about? All you have to ask yourself is whether the procedure you describe will produce the correct output. If it does, hooray!; if it doesn't, it should be simple to fix it.